# Protect users from accidental extremely loud volume in the browser

Tags: javascript, web, audio, volume, user-experience

I'm building a flexible audio application where users can accidentally make things too loud. What are best practices to prevent extremely loud volume?

It looks like I can try using [Analyser Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode) from [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) to detect the loudness, and then reduce the volume based on that. Is there a more standard way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this reasonably well by using [Analyser Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode) to detect the loud volume, and [GainNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode) to decrease the volume. Followed code from [visualizer examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API):

```js
const safety = audioContext.createGain()
const safetyAnalyser = audioContext.createAnalyser()

safetyAnalyser.connect(audioContext.destination)
safety.connect(safetyAnalyser)
protectEars(safetyAnalyser, safety)

applicationOutput.connect(safety)


function protectEars(analyser: AnalyserNode, gain: GainNode) {
  analyser.fftSize = 2048
  analyser.minDecibels = -90

  const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount
  const fbc_array = new Uint8Array(bufferLength)

  analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(fbc_array)
  const dataArray = new Uint8Array(fbc_array.buffer)

  let timesHit255 = 0

  for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; ++i) {
    if (dataArray[i] === 255) timesHit255++
  }

  // Magic number found with casual experimentation
  if (timesHit255 > 200) {
    gain.gain.value /= 2
    sendNotificationBox('VOLUME REDUCED BECAUSE IT WAS TOO LOUD!')
  } else {
    // Slowly restore? They can also deal with it and just keep making it "louder" on their side
  }

  setTimeout(protectEars.bind(null, analyser, gain), 100)
}
```

The reason it uses `setTimeout` as opposed to `requestAnimationFrame` is because RAF does not get executed when the user switches tabs (while setTimeout does), and the audio may still be unpredictable so you'll still want to watch it.